# Select unique rows with where in clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, where-in

I am trying to return one `json` per unique value in a column.

However, when I try to select from a sub-query the entire result set is returned.

**Example Table**

```
| json   | column | 
|--------|--------|
| {obj1} | 1      |
| {obj2} | 1      |
| {obj3} | 2      |
```

**Example Query**

```
select distinct
[json]
from someTable 
where [column] in (
  select distinct 
  [column]
  from someTable
)
```

**Actual Output**

```
| json   |
|--------|
| {obj1} |
| {obj2} | 
| {obj3} |
```

**Expected Output**

```
| json   |
|--------|
| {obj1} |
| {obj3} |
```

How can I select just 1 `json` per unique column value?

Comment: Is there a primary key like and id in the table?

Comment: @forpas Yes, an auto-incrementing integer primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If doesn't Matter output Related To Column is  `obj1 Or obj2` you must Use Group By Like this :

```
SELECT
  Min(JSon) AS Json ,Column
FROM
 someTable 
Group By column
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 1st `[json]` of each `column` then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.[json] from (
  select 
    [json],
    row_number() over (partition by column order by id) rn
  from someTable 
) t
where t.rn = 1
```